# The meaning of "get away with a light sentence"

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

I have a question with the meaning of "get away with a light sentence".

Does "get away with a light sentence" mean that
"the person escaped a light sentence" or
mean that "the person was punished, but the punishment was lighter or less severe than what might have been expected"?

And does "get off with a light sentence" have the same meaning as "get away with a light sentence"?

Appreciated if anyone could give me a hint.

Comment: Have you tried the dictionary? See [sense 2 on OxfordLD.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/get-away-with)

Comment: *Get away* means escape. *Get away with* means succeed luckily, close to *get off with*.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of **to get away** is "to manage to escape (from a situation)".

When combined with a prepositional phrase headed by **with**, the object of the preposition will refer to a milder consequence than the circumstances typically result in.

The situation can be implicit because it is understood from context:

> He got away with a stern warning.

Or the thing escaped can be explicit:

> He got away from the inferno with only his eyebrows singed.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

It means that they were punished only lightly.

"Get off with a light sentence" has the same meaning as "get away with a light sentence".

Comment: Thanks, one following up question, how do you understand "get away with murder"

Comment: This depends on the context and who is doing the action. "To get away with" can mean either not being punished for an action (specifying an infraction: lying, murder, stealing) or facing a light punishment (specifying a punishment: warning, light sentence).